# How to permanently deny uac requests for an application

Tags: windows-8, uac

I regularly get annoyed by things like java asking me if it can go check for and install updates and its really annoying.

The uac dialog appears and does its usual screen dimming, which is great for that out of the ordinary request but for routine requests I want to be able to provide an answer to this dialog and tell windows that "for this application never ask me again as this is always the answer".

I've seen a few questions on here about whitelists for uac ... is there black list too?
Here's one example:
[Windows 7: Always remember UAC choice for an application](https://superuser.com/questions/119086/windows-7-always-remember-uac-choice-for-an-application?rq=1)

Like the others though this only addresses the "whitelisting" side of uac, i want to permanently black list the app to shut it up (unfortunately i need java on my machine for a few of my applications to use otherwise I would just remove it).

I'm half tempted to put the problematic apps in their own VM but thats a little inconvient, more so than this annoying prompt.

Oh and in case it matters, im using windows 8.

Comment: Why don't you just disable the service that checks for java updates if it begs you that much.  Since you want to deny the ability for the service to install the update you lose nothing by doing so.