# Can I have Windows 7 always allow Eudora to run?

Tags: windows-7, uac

I use Eudora (an older email client program).

When I open my shortcut to Eudora, a User Account Control dialog appears asking me if I want to allow the program to make changes to my computer, before it starts running.

How can I get Windows 7 to not do this, for Eudora only?

I see that the UAC dialog says I can change when Windows does this, but it only lets me choose a level for all of Windows. I don't want to change that from its current level (which is to ask when programs try to "make changes to my computer").

I tried setting the shortcut I use to launch Eudora to "run with Administrator privileges" but this does not seem to help.

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/119086/windows-7-always-remember-uac-choice-for-an-application?rq=1 Observe the task scheduler method seen there, it might be the better method for your other symptoms. it is quite a few steps, but all that stuff is built-in, so no downloads. That method does not work  when more parts and pieces are existing for a program, works well for the single executable no services style of program, and portableisable types.

Comment: this http://winaero.com/comment.php?comment.news.152 program was not shown in the answers there, if you get a clean download and dont follow stupid download links and all :-) i have not seen added install junk from winaero (yet), so it might be a good one also.